# How to check for length of optarg and if it is numeric

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, getopt

I am using `getopt` to parse arguments passed to my c program. I want to check if the`optarg` is all numeric right at the point of parsing it, but I do not know how to get length of the value in the `optarg`:

```
int opt;
unsigned short port;

    while((opt =  getopt(argc, argv, "p:")) != EOF) {

        switch(opt) {
             case 'p':
             for(int i = 0; i < OPTARG_LENGTH; i++) {
                if(!isnum[optarg[i]]) exit();
             }
                port = strtoul(optarg, NULL, 10);
             break;
        }
```

So how do i find out `OPTARG_LENGTH` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`strlen(optarg)` would give you that information, but don't try to check for integer value with that naive method, let `strtoul` do the exact checking for you.

For that you have to modify the way you're calling it to pass a pointer on a char pointer so `strtoul` points out the error if there's one.

(For instance, if the number exceeds unsigned long limit, your check is useless)

Also note that `port` is an unsigned short, so you have to perform an extra check before assigning it, or you'll get overflow.

```
char *temp;
unsigned long port_ul = strtoul(optarg,&temp,10);

if (optarg != temp && *temp == '\0' && port_ul <= USHRT_MAX)  // needs #include <limits.h>
  {
    // argument is properly parsed: ok
    port = port_ul;
  }
```

the check is done in 3 parts:

- check that `*temp` actually points on the end of the string
- check that the string isn't empty (often forgotten, thanks to chux for the tip in another answer)
- since there's no standard string to unsigned short conversion, use `limits.h` to ensure you're not getting overflow when assigning to unsigned short.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer! can you please tell me what does `optarg != temp` do and what is a good way to check for the overflow?

Comment: Already upvoted, but if an empty string was passed to `strtoul()`, and the empty string test was forgotten, you would have `port == 0` (which may or may not be desired), but no undefined behavior, yes?

Comment: yes, `strtoul` would return 0 in that case, which is not acceptable for a port number so you could also just convert with lousy `atoi` and check for > 0 in that case, but that's not very academic and cannot be generalized.

Comment: lousy `atoi` I said :) note that if `strtoul` is used with `NULL` as a second argument, it's not very useful either... the art of parsing integers properly in c...